# Dynamic sql : multi-part identifier could not be found error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ViewEffortSummary
            @UserID                         INT         ,
            @Project_Name                   nVARCHAR(40),
            @Date                           DATETIME    
        AS 
        BEGIN     
    DECLARE @query          nVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @T_EmpID        nVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @T_ProjName     nVARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @T_Date         nVARCHAR(15)
    SET @T_EmpID = convert(VARCHAR(10),@UserID);
    SET @T_ProjName = @Project_Name;
    SET @T_Date = convert(VARCHAR(15),@Date,111);
    SET @query = 'select '''+@T_EmpID+''' as EmployeeID';

    IF((select Proj_Team_Setup
        from tblPSU 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',Proj_Team_Setup';
    IF((select Infra_Setup
        from tblPSU 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',Infra_Setup';
    IF((select tblPSU.Doc_Work 
        from tblPSU where 
        Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',tblPSU.Doc_Work';
    IF((select tblPSU.Rework 
        from tblPSU 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',tblPSU.Rework';    


    IF((select Proj_Mgmt_Telcom 
        from tblPC 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',Proj_Mgmt_Telcom';
    IF((select tblPC.Doc_Work 
        from tblPC 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',tblPC.Doc_Work';
    IF((select tblPC.Rework 
        from tblPC 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',tblPC.Rework'; 


    IF((select Cust_Test_Proces 
        from tblKT 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',Cust_Test_Proces';
    IF((select tblKT.Doc_Work 
        from tblKT 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',tblKT.Doc_Work';
    IF((select tblKT.Rework 
        from tblKT 
        where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
        and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
        and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
        SET @query += ',tblKT.Rework';     

    SET @query += ' from tblPSU a 
                    join tblPC b 
                    on a.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID 
                    and a.Project_Name = b.Project_Name 
                    and a.Date_of_work = b.Date_of_work 
                    join tblKT c 
                    on b.Employee_ID = c.Employee_ID 
                    and b.Project_Name = c.Project_Name 
                    and b.Date_of_work = c.Date_of_work 
                    where 
                    a.Employee_ID = '+@T_EmpID+'
                    and a.Project_Name = '+@T_ProjName+
                    ' and a.Date_of_work = '''+@T_Date+''''
    IF (@query IS NOT NULL)
    Exec (@query)
    END

    EXEC sp_ViewEffortSummary '2312456','abc','2014-06-17 00:00:00.000'
```

on executing this proc I'm retrieving error as

```
Invalid column name 'abc' and 
The multi-part identifier "tblPC.Doc_Work" could not be bound
```

Could anyone please help me in solving this ?

Comment: Can you `PRINT @query` and post it?

Comment: It sounds likely you're not escaping your project name, have you considered using `and a.Project_Name = '''+@T_ProjName+''' and` to see if that resolves one of your issues?

Comment: Alias name is the problem for _The multi-part identifier_ error

Comment: @Kaf : select '2312456' as EmployeeID,Infra_Setup,Proj_Mgmt_Telcom,b.Doc_Work,b.Rework from   tblPSU a join tblPC b 
on a.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID and a.Project_Name = b.Project_Name and a.Date_of_work = b.Date_of_work 
join tblKT c 
on b.Employee_ID = c.Employee_ID and b.Project_Name = c.Project_Name and b.Date_of_work = c.Date_of_work 
where 
a.Employee_ID = 2312456 and a.Project_Name = 'abc' and a.Date_of_work = 'Jun 17 2014 12:'

Comment: @scragar : Thanks ProjName is valid after using quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your query as:

1. In the very first declaration you have written `@UserID INT` but
   when executing Sproc you have written it as string as '2312456'. It
   should be 2312456 as shown below or else change the declaration to
   `nVARCHAR(10)`.
2. When tables are aliased then use Aliases to refer columns in Select like `a.Proj_Team_Setup`..
3. As abc is a string correct quotes should be used to repesent it as 'abc' in your final query.

Following should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ViewEffortSummary
            @UserID INT,
            @Project_Name nVARCHAR(40),
            @Date DATETIME  
        AS 
        BEGIN     
DECLARE @query          nVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @T_EmpID        nVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @T_ProjName     nVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @T_Date         nVARCHAR(15)
SET @T_EmpID = convert(VARCHAR(10),@UserID);
SET @T_ProjName = @Project_Name;
SET @T_Date = convert(VARCHAR(30),@Date,111);
SET @query = 'select '''+@T_EmpID+''' as EmployeeID';

IF((select Proj_Team_Setup
    from tblPSU 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',a.Proj_Team_Setup';
IF((select Infra_Setup
    from tblPSU 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',a.Infra_Setup';
IF((select tblPSU.Doc_Work 
    from tblPSU where 
    Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',a.Doc_Work';
IF((select tblPSU.Rework 
    from tblPSU 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',a.Rework';    


IF((select Proj_Mgmt_Telcom 
    from tblPC 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',b.Proj_Mgmt_Telcom';
IF((select tblPC.Doc_Work 
    from tblPC 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',b.Doc_Work';
IF((select tblPC.Rework 
    from tblPC 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',b.Rework'; 


IF((select Cust_Test_Proces 
    from tblKT 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',c.Cust_Test_Proces';
IF((select tblKT.Doc_Work 
    from tblKT 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',c.Doc_Work';
IF((select tblKT.Rework 
    from tblKT 
    where Employee_ID = @T_EmpID 
    and Project_Name = @T_ProjName 
    and Date_of_work = @Date) is not null)
    SET @query += ',c.Rework'; 
    SET @query += ' from tblPSU a 
                    join tblPC b 
                    on a.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID 
                    and a.Project_Name = b.Project_Name 
                    and a.Date_of_work = b.Date_of_work 
                    join tblKT c 
                    on b.Employee_ID = c.Employee_ID 
                    and b.Project_Name = c.Project_Name 
                    and b.Date_of_work = c.Date_of_work 
                    where 
                    a.Employee_ID = '''+@T_EmpID+'''
                    and a.Project_Name = '''+@T_ProjName+
                    ''' and a.Date_of_work = '''+@T_Date+''''

IF (@query IS NOT NULL)
    Exec (@query)
    END

    EXEC sp_ViewEffortSummary 2312456 ,'abc','2014-06-17 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: After adding the alias name, I get this error on execution 

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: That's because it's getting truncated when converted to varchar(15) so @T_Date has value 'Jun 17 2014 12:' which is an incompatible format... replace it with varchar(30) and it will work. check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You use alias for `tblPSU` and `tblPC` and must use **`Alias.YourColumnName`** for example use `a.Doc_Work` and `b.Doc_Work` instead of `tblPSU.Doc_Work` and `tblPS.Doc_Work`

```
 tblPSU.Doc_Work --> a.Doc_Work

 tblPc.Doc_Work  --> b.Doc_Work

 tblKT.Rework    --> c.Rework

 tblPC.Rework    --> b.Rework
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alias as provided ('a'/'b') in join and use "quotes" in the dynamic query for projectname(nvarchar).try with a.Project_Name = '''+@T_ProjName+'''.The date column has it